# android add View above ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar, custom-view

I have a activity in fullscreen mode. In the activity is a ActionBar with 4 Tabs.
My problem is that I would like to "simulate" my own statusbar on the top of the activity. But I can't add a view above the statusbar.

When I set a customview to the ActionBar (and set .setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true) ) it basically works - the custom view is above the ActionBar-Tabs. But on this soluton I can't control the height of the custom view - its always statically the same height.

Have you any ideas to solve this problem?

Thanks much and best regards
Tobi

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can do that avoiding action bar

Instead of using action bar create a Linear or relative layout like you have your action bar .

Give the layout a fixed height exactly same as the action bar . You can find the exact height of action bar for different scenarios from the stencil in the zip. http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Downloads_20130814.zip

Then use Tabhost with fragments to display tabs since tabhost can be placed anywhere you are free to use them however you want.

If you wanna continue with this way let me know i will help you with tabhost code to display tabs.

Here is the TAbhost example code with fragments

1.>Add this to your xml

```
<TabHost
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@null"

        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also replace the second framelayout with a viewpager to provide swipable tabs , If you plan to do so then don't change the id just replace FrameLayout tag with viewpager

2.> Place this code in your activity

```
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();


    mTabManager = new TabManager(this, mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabManager.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragment1").setIndicator("Fragment1"), FragmentOne.class,
            null);
    mTabManager.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragment2").setIndicator("Fragment2"),
            FragmentTwo.class, null);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
}

/**
 * This is a helper class that implements a generic mechanism for
 * associating fragments with the tabs in a tab host. It relies on a trick.
 * Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or Intent that
 * each tab will show. This is not sufficient for switching between
 * fragments. So instead we make the content part of the tab host 0dp high
 * (it is not shown) and the TabManager supplies its own dummy view to show
 * as the tab content. It listens to changes in tabs, and takes care of
 * switch to the correct fragment shown in a separate content area whenever
 * the selected tab changes.
 */
public static class TabManager implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final int mContainerId;
    private final HashMap<String, TabInfo> mTabs = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();
    TabInfo mLastTab;

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabManager(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
            int containerId) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mContainerId = containerId;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mActivity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state. If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        info.fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (info.fragment != null && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(info.fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        mTabs.put(tag, info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        TabInfo newTab = mTabs.get(tabId);
        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                }
            }
            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity,
                            newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                    ft.add(mContainerId, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }

            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            mActivity.getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }
```

This a running code you dont have to change anything besides the Fragments in addTab method , place your Fragments there .

For every Fragment you have call addTab method .

Comment: Very nice idea. I read that the TabHost is deprecated and we should use the ActionBar some time ago. Is that so?

Comment: TabActivity is depricated which was used earlier with TabHost but TabHost is not deprecated and you can use it with fragments

Comment: Ahh okay :-) have you a example how to set a tabhost in a activity with fragments?

Comment: Hello Ravi, thank you very much for your answer. Is ist really so that I have to import the support.v4 lib into my project to run this code? What do you think how long is this feauture still supported? The risk is too high in my case. My solution is a "own/faked ActionBar" at the moment. These ActionBar is a Fragment with a TableLayout (4 columns, 2 rows) included. The first row includes ImageButtons, the second row includes the SelectedTabIndicator. The logic to switch the "tabs" are still coded in java (code-behind). If the class is finished i will post it. Best regards Tobi

Comment: well if you are not going to use viewpager then you dont have include support lib just replace the FragmentActivity with normal activity and supportFragmentManager with fragmentManager and import fragment class from app package instead of support package